# Having two generic methods, one with a constraint. Swift 3.1 started preferring one without constraint.

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a generic class with two generic methods one of which has a requirement to conform to a protocol. After updating to XCode 8.3.2 the method with no constraint is always executed even if the type conforms to specified protocol.

```
protocol AProtocol {
    init(dict: dict) {

    }
}

struct AStruct: AProtocol { 
    init(dict: dict) { 

    }
}


struct Container<T>  {
    var object: Any?
    init<T: AProtocol>(dict: [String : Any], type: T) {
        object = T(dict: dict)
    }
    init<T>(dict [String : Any], type: T) {
        object = dict
    } 
}

class AClass<S> {
    var value: S


    init<S>(value: S) {
        self.value = value
        let container = Container(dict: [], type: S.self)

    }
}
```

So in the initializer of AClass the container's initializer without constraint will always be called regardless whether S conforms to AProtocol or not.

My question is does anyone know workaround or at least know what has changes with newer swift versions, because this used to work properly on swift 3.0?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project (CMD + Shift + K)? Also, try reseting simulator and deleting DerivedData content.

Comment: @ThiagoAM I have done those things. Also I test on an actual device. Nothing helps.